# ¿Cómo restar una "cantidad" de un tabla B en una tabla A? JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

El proyecto es un tipo de inventario, donde el usuario guarda ciertas cantidades y después entrega otras cantidades, por ej el guarda 100 jabones y luego entra 25 jabones.
En la tabla A me encargo de guardar las cantidades que ingresan (con un código) y en la tabla B las cantidades que egresan.
Mi consulta es como puedo actualizar la tabla A, haciendo la resta de las cantidades de la tabla B sobre la tabla A?
Siguiendo el ejemplo anterior, Si el usuario tenia 100 jabones en la tabla A y entrego 25(tabla B), ahora en la tabla A debería tener 75 jabones.
De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es que manejes una única tabla para ambas operaciones en donde tengas un campo para el registro de tus ingresos de productos y luego, otro campo para tus egresos.

Luego, cuando desees obtener la diferencia o el "stock" de cada producto, haces una consulta como esta:

`SELECT id, {otro_campo} (ingresos - egresos) AS stock from {nombre_tabla}`

Reemplaza el {otro_campo} o agrega más campos de quienes deseas obtener los datos, además del nombre_tabla.

La consulta devolverá los datos de la tabla, mas el stock de cada producto, el cual se almacena en la variable "stock", que proviene de la diferencia entre el valor almacenado en el campo ingresos y el valor almacenado en el campo egresos

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo con este código! espero les sirva a los que estén haciendo algo similar

```
    void RestarCantidades(){

String sql ="UPDATE tabla_A A INNER JOIN tabla_B B ON A.codigo_A = B.codigo_B SET A.CANTIDAD_A = A.CANTIDAD_A - B.CANTIDAD_B";
        try {
                cn=con.getConnection();
                st=cn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(sql);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }
```

Después este metodo lo llame dentro de un botón

```
private void BTNPRUEBAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    RestarCantidades();
}
```